# Checking Synchronization issue in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL. I want to make that the SP should work under load. Means it should not have any synchronization issues.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOldDeviceID]
(
    @OldDeviceID VARCHAR(500)
    ,@NewDeviceID  VARCHAR(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @TranCount INT;
SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

BEGIN TRY
    IF @TranCount = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ELSE
        SAVE TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

    IF @NewDeviceID <> '-1' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @NewDeviceID) 
        BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [DeviceCatalog]
                ([os]
                ,[uniqueid]
                ,[address]
                ,[location]
                ,[culture]
                ,[city]
                ,[country]
                ,[other]
                ,[lastmodifieddate]
                ,[createddate]
                ,[IsActive]
                ,[IPAddress]
                ,[NativeDeviceID]
                ,[IsDeleted])
        SELECT  [os]
            ,@NewDeviceID
            ,[address]
            ,[location]
            ,[culture]
            ,[city]
            ,[country]
            ,[other]
            ,GETDATE()
            ,GETDATE()
            ,[IsActive]
            ,[IPAddress]
            ,[NativeDeviceID]
            ,[IsDeleted]
        FROM    [DeviceCatalog]
        WHERE   [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID;
    END
    DELETE FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID; -- Always Delete old one
        LBEXIT:
    IF @TranCount = 0
        COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
    SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

        IF @XState = -1
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
            rollback
        IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

        RAISERROR ('DeleteOldDeviceID: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    END CATCH
 END
```

**Edit:**, Is this equal to above SQL?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOldDeviceID]
(
    @OldDeviceID VARCHAR(500)
    ,@NewDeviceID  VARCHAR(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TranCount INT;
    SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF @TranCount = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ELSE
            SAVE TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

        IF @NewDeviceID <> '-1' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @NewDeviceID) 
            BEGIN   
                UPDATE  [DeviceCatalog]
                SET [UniqueID] = @NewDeviceID
                WHERE   [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID;
            END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID; -- Always Delete old one
        END
        LBEXIT:
            IF @TranCount = 0
                COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
        SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();
            IF @XState = -1
                ROLLBACK;
            IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
                ROLLBACK
            IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

            RAISERROR ('DeleteOldDeviceID: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the Second Query won't Delete anything.

In the statement prior to the `delete` you change the **oldID** to the **newID** so there aren't any records with the **oldID** in that table.

---

**Difference between the two Queries**

The first Query, inserts new records into the table, then deletes the records with the **oldID**

The Second Query, updates all the records removing the **oldID**'s and replacing it with the **newID**'s, so instead of inserting and then deleting the old records, it updates the old records `UniqueID` column

These both do very different things.